# Why does Dr. Isaac point his finger to the bible in the meeting?

Tags: plot-explanation, resident-evil, resident-evil-the-final-chapter

In **Resident Evil: The Final Chapter**, Dr. Isaac points his finger to the bible in the meeting and says these words:

> It's been done once before with great success.

[image: character with a finger on a holy bible]

Why does he do that?

Answer (score 6):

## It's a reference to the Great Flood and Noah's Ark.

The proposal is to emulate the destruction of humanity by God in the Bible with the exception of a chosen few who were saved in Noah's Ark.

This is actually clear from the dialogue.

> I propose that we
>   end the world...
>
> But on our terms. An orchestrated apocalypse.
>
> One that would cleanse the world of its' population but leave its infrastructure and resources intact.
>
> *It's been done once before. With great success.*
>
> The chosen few will ride out the storm, **not in an ark as in the book of Genesis**, but in safety.
>
> Underground.